# How to find explicit formula using backwards iteration

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

[image: Sequencing]

For this problem I tried to solve it by iterating downward so:

a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n-1</sub> - n

a<sub>n-1</sub> = 2*(2a<sub>n-2</sub> - (n-1)) - n = 4a<sub>n-2</sub> - 3n + 2

a<sub>n-2</sub> = 2*(4a<sub>n-3</sub> - 3n + 2) - n = 8a<sub>n-3</sub> - 7n + 4

a<sub>n-3</sub> = 2*(8a<sub>n-4</sub> - 7n + 4) - n = 16a<sub>n-4</sub> - 15n + 8

Then I figured that this could be rewritten in this format:

2<sup>k+1</sup>a<sub>n-k</sub> - (2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1)n + 2<sup>k</sup>

And then I believe that I am supposed to rewrite this equation using the sigma notation, but I'm not sure if I did the steps correctly because I don't understand how to rewrite what I have found in the form outline in the problem.

Comment: Looks like Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=2a_{n-1}-n\\
2a_{n-1}&=4a_{n-2}-2(n-1)\\
4a_{n-2}&=8a_{n-3}-4(n-2)\\
\vdots\\
2^{n-1}a_{1}&=2^{n}a_{0}-2^{n-1}(1)\\
\end{align}$$
by summing all steps

$$a_n=2^{n}a_0-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^{i}(n-i)$$

$$a_n=3\cdot2^{n}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}n2^{i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i2^{i}$$

> $$a_n=3\cdot2^{n}-n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^{i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i2^{i}$$